# Mock addEventListener for google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

I've this code:

```
const eventNames = ['ready', 'click']
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(mapRef)
const mapConfig = { streetViewControl: false }
this.map = new maps.Map(node, mapConfig)

eventNames.forEach(e => {
  this.listeners[e] = this.map.addListener(e, this.handleEvent(e))
})
```

And I want to test it but I'm receiving this error: `this.map.addListener is not a function`. I'm mocking like this:

```
window.addEventListener = jest.fn()
const google = {
  maps: {
    LatLng: jest.fn(),
    Map: jest.fn(),
    event: jest.fn()
  }
}

const wrapper = shallow(
  <Map google={google}>
    <Component />
  </Map>
)
```

Can any one help to mock this part?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the how to mock this:

```
const google = {
  maps: {
    LatLng: jest.fn(),
    Map: function() { return { addListener: jest.fn() } },
    event: { trigger: jest.fn() }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at 
jest-google-maps-mock